# How to run java directly in terminal

Tags: command-line, java

In python; i can use this to start python interactive interpreter:-

`$ python3`

`>>>......`

But i am unable to start java interpreter directly in terminal without using java file and then compiling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via installing java [jdk version 9](http://www.javahelps.com/2017/09/install-oracle-jdk-9-on-linux.html) and then using `jshell`.

Just simply use this command:-

`$ jshell`
Then this will get prompted:-

```
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 9.0.4
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell>
```

Then just run your code there.

Comment: Could you include information on how to install JDK 9?

Comment: it may form a next topic; but installing jdk 9 can be done via [here](http://www.javahelps.com/2017/09/install-oracle-jdk-9-on-linux.html)